# how to get a data from a DB using MYSQL and store it in javascript Array

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any possible way to get a data from a DB using MYSQL and store it in javascript Array?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5); 
// of course this array can be created by looping through your mysql result set
// and doing a mysql_fetch_assoc
// for example, $sql = your query here 
// mysql_fetch_assoc($result); etc

echo json_encode($arr);
?>

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Then you can do something like

```
<script type="text/javsacript">
var abc = "<? echo json_encode($arr);?>";
</script>
```

OR

```
echo '<script type="text/javsacript">
        var abc ="'.json_encode($arr).'";
    </script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch it as an [associative array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc), and then use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create a JavaScript array, stored in a string.

Answer (score 1):

.

```
// first, build your query:
$sql = "SELECT name, email FROM users";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

// then build up your data
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

//then write it in a way Javascript can understand:

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
    . "var users = " . json_encode($rows) . ";\n"
    . "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a pretty vague question, but I think [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) is what you're looking
for.

EDIT: Of course JSON will workout too and might even be more straight forward...

Comment: you don't necessarily have to be making asynchronous calls to want to get info from a database into javascript!